# un escapeing special characters using java

Tags: java

I have give following value (escaping using Windows-1252)

ABC &#145 ; &#146 ; &#147 ; &#148 ; &#226 ;, &#234 ;, &#238 ;, &#244 ;, &#251 ;
*(I need to add space to display exact value actual there is no space between number and ;)*

but the actual value is and I want the same value as below

**ABC ‘ ’ “ ” â, ê, î, ô, û**

I have tried HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(decodedString); but did not work
I am getting output like 
**ABC    â, ê, î, ô, û**

‘ ’ “ ” is removed.

Can you please provide how to do this in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote characters are probably still in the string, they are just invisible when displayed. That's because in Unicode or ISO 8859-1, the code point 145 is not assigned to a visible character.

The best solution (if possible) is to pass the encoding to the `unescapeHtml` method.

An alternative is to call `htmlUnescape` first and then map the cp1252 codepoints to the corresponding Unicode code points, using the following code:

```
String unescapeHtmlCp1252(String input) {
    String nohtml = HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(input);
    byte[] bytes = nohtml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    String result = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("cp1252"));
    return result;
}
```

When you step through this code with a debugger and inspect the `nohtml` string, you will probably see characters with the value 145, 146, and so on. This means that the characters are still there at this point.

Later, when the characters are converted into pixels by using a font, these characters do not have a definition and are therefore just ignored. But until this step, they are still there.

Comment: Can you throw some more lights on it? I am not getting your point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for that.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);");
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();


    String s = "ABC&#145;&#146;&#226;D";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int startIdx = 0; 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0};
    while(startIdx < s.length() && m.find(startIdx)) {
        if (m.start() > startIdx) {
            out.append(s.substring(startIdx, m.start()));
        }
        // fetch the numeric value from the encoding and put it into a byte array 
        bytes[0] = (byte)Short.parseShort(m.group(1));
        // convert the windows 1252 encoded byte array into a java string 
        out.append(new String(bytes,"Windows-1252"));   
        startIdx = m.end();
    }

    if (startIdx < s.length()) {
        out.append(s.substring(startIdx));
    }
```

The output / result will be something like

> ABC‘’âD

Comment: You can make the code simpler by using `Matcher.appendReplacement`.